# StompSessionHandler not calling handleFrame in afterConnected block?

Tags: java, spring, stomp, spring-websocket

I have a fairly simple setup to test Stomp support in Spring.

I was planning on using JS to send messages to the queue and receive and handle them in Spring app. However, it doesn't seem to work for some reason.

JS client:

```
var ws = new SockJS('/hello');
client = Stomp.over(ws);
...
client.subscribe('jms.queue.test', function(message) {}
...
client.send("jms.queue.test", {}, "message");
```

Spring config (mostly useless at the moment, since i don't use `/app` destination):

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableStompBrokerRelay("jms.topic", "jms.queue");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
        config.setPathMatcher(new AntPathMatcher("."));
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/hello").withSockJS();
    }
}
```

Spring Boot App:

```
@Component
public class BusinessLogic implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    hulloController controller;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        stuff(args);
    }

    public void stuff(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(20000);//sleep while spring boot fully initializes
        controller.waitForGreet();
    }
}
```

Controller (not a real `@Controller`, i don't plan to use MVC):

```
@Component
public class hulloController {

    private SimpMessagingTemplate template;

    @Autowired
    StompSessionHandler handler;

    @Autowired
    public hulloController(SimpMessagingTemplate template) {
        this.template = template;
    }

    public void waitForGreet() {
        System.out.println("Entered Listener");

        WebSocketClient transport = new StandardWebSocketClient();
        WebSocketStompClient stompClient = new WebSocketStompClient(transport);
        stompClient.setMessageConverter(new StringMessageConverter());
        stompClient.connect("ws://127.0.0.1:61613/stomp", handler);
    }
}
```

And finally, the handler:

```
@Component
public class SessionHandler implements StompSessionHandler {
    @Override
    public void afterConnected(StompSession stompSession, StompHeaders stompHeaders) {
        System.out.println("Connected!");
        StompFrameHandler handler = new StompFrameHandler() {
            @Override
            public Type getPayloadType(StompHeaders stompHeaders) {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public void handleFrame(StompHeaders stompHeaders, Object o) {
                System.out.println("received " + o.toString());
            }
        };

        //StompSession.Subscription s = stompSession.subscribe("jms.queue.test", handler);

        stompSession.send("jms.queue.test", "hello!");
    }
    ...
}
```

If i comment the `client.subscribe` part, `client.send` works properly, message is received and rendered in JS, so the queue names and connection URL are fine. I also tried using `SockJSClient` as a Transport but it doesn't help.

When i send messages from JS, for about 1 or 2 minutes half of them isn't showing up (as it would be if the subscription would be working), then JS starts receiving 100% of the messages.

I've seen plenty of almost identical code on github today, and i just don't see what the issue might be here.

Answer (score 1):

```
 //StompSession.Subscription s = stompSession.subscribe("jms.queue.test", handler);

 stompSession.send("jms.queue.test", "hello!");
```

The STOMP over WebSocket is a an `async` protocol.

You call there `subscribe` and got to the `send`. There is no guaranty that the subscription will happen already, when you start to send something to that destination.

Consider to use `StompSession.Subscription` and its `addReceiptTask()` to send messages to the destination after the confirmation for the subscription.

And you should enable `StompSession.setAutoReceipt(true)` to make that working with your STOMP Broker.

Comment: Yeah, i know STOMP is async. I'm not expecting this "hello!" to be received, it's there to show that connection to the broker theoretically is working.

Please look at my JS snippet, that's actually the way i send messages to that queue.

Comment: Your JS has the same vulnerability. You should `send` in the `subscribe`.  Or somewhere late, but not directly just after the `subscribe`.

Comment: I guess i should have pasted more of my JS, those methods are executed in different parts of the JS app. As for the problem, I have found a solution, even though i have no idea why it works now. Thx for the help.

Answer (score 1):

So, apparently switching from implementing `StompSessionHandler` to extending `StompSessionHandlerAdapter` for my handler did the trick.

I have absolutely no idea why, but i guess this passage from Spring docs for `StompSessionHandler` is there for a reason:

> "Implementations of this interface should consider extending
>   StompSessionHandlerAdapter."

Comment: That does not make sense. Looking to the code there no any place for the `instanceof  StompSessionHandlerAdapter`. I'm sure that you have changed anything else in your code, but let it be if you decided this way...

Comment: @ArtemBilan it's in my handler implementation. Here http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.3.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/messaging/simp/stomp/StompSessionHandler.html here's the javadoc from which i copied the quote.
I just swapped `SessionHandler implements StompSessionHandler` for `SessionHandler extends StompSessionHandlerAdapter`.

Answer (score 1):

```
        @Override
        public Type getPayloadType(StompHeaders stompHeaders) {
            return null;
        }
```

because of this line: you supply unhandled converter - it throws exception. But it's not logged or anything. check out the code and paste proper Type instead of null